# cross-env memory leak with npm run dev on Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, laravel-mix, cross-env

I am installing a Laravel project (version 6.17.1) on a Docker Toolbox instance on a Windows 10 machine. Inside my Docker instance, I can run `composer install` fine, and `npm i` fine, but when I run `npm run dev`, but initially, I was getting error about cross-env:

```
sh: 1: cross-env: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I then installed cross-env manually, and now I know that this node module has been installed, as in my node_modules folder I can see a cross-env folder - however, the error message persisted.

Looking at some other answers, I can see that I may need to alter my package.json file - the scripts initially looked like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
```

Following [florencebib's](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/478) example, my package.json now looklike:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "node node_modules/cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "node node_modules/cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "node node_modules/cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "hot": "node node_modules/cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "production": "node node_modules/cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
    }
}
```

As I have updated package.json, I run `rm -rf node_modules rm package-lock.json yarn.lock npm cache clear --force`, install the node modules and once more try to run dev, but now I am getting the following error:

```
<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xa295e0 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x9782df node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xb99c2e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb99fa7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xd3a3b5  [node]
 6: 0xd3ad5b v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [node]
 7: 0xd48b52 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xd499a5 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0xd4c36c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
10: 0xd1ba0b v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
11: 0x104bdaf v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
12: 0x13a5a99  [node]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `node node_modules/cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Other things that I have tried before getting to this point:

- npm install --save-dev cross-env
- npm i cross-env -g
- npm rebuild
- deleting and reinstalling node modules
- clearing cache
- using Yarn instead of npm

Have I done something wrong to cause a memory leak? Or am I going the wrong way about this? Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update your Nodejs to the latest version.
2. Delete the "node_modules" folder then run the following commands

   ```
   npm install 
   npm run dev
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently after I launched a few new containers my old one showed me this error.
I've increased the RAM allocated for docker from 2GB to 5GB and it doesn't fail anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.4.0",
        "alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "jquery": "^3.5",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "laravel-mix-merge-manifest": "^2.1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.16",
        "postcss": "^8.4.6",
        "sass": "^1.32.1",
        "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.18"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "codemirror": "^6.0.1"
    }
}
```

paste this in your package.json and then delete the package-lock.json , delete the node_modules folder and run npm install. then followed by npm run dev and thats all... its 100% worked for me.LARAVEL 8.x , 9.x ,6.x

Comment: You may want to edit your answer to explain why this resolves the issue, further guidance can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)